# Custom Key logic to avoid shuffling

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

I am using Flink 1.11.

My application read data from Kafka, so messages are already in ordered in Kafka partition. After consuming message from Kafka, I want to apply TumblingWindow. As per Flink Documentation, keyBy is required to use TumblingWindow. Using keyby , it means it will trigger shuffling of data, which I want to avoid. Since in each Task slot, records are already in ordered (due to its consumption from Kafka), how can shuffling be avoided ? Number of parallelism can be greater, equal or lesser to Kafka partitions. my concern is :

1. Can TumblingWindow be used without keyby ?
2. If not, how keyby can be customised to ensure data remain on same task slot and no shuffling is triggered.

Comment: It seems a quite common question, wondering why Flink doesn't have an out of box  solution yet.

Answer (score 0):

What are you asking for is very difficult to achieve using the DataStream API. But the SQL/Table API automatically applies various optimizations when you use window-valued table functions, which will likely be good enough. See the docs for [tumble window TVF](https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-stable/docs/dev/table/sql/queries/window-tvf/#tumble), [mini-batch aggregation](https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-stable/docs/dev/table/tuning/#minibatch-aggregation) and [local/global aggregation](https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-stable/docs/dev/table/tuning/#local-global-aggregation).

Note however that window TVFs were added to Flink in 1.13.